# set global variables not working mysql

Tags: mysql

I have reinstalled MySQL server recently because the previous one crashed somehow. I  want to change some server variable values by using SET GLOBAL, e.g.

```
    SET GLOBAL query_alloc_block_size = 1024
```

(1024 being the minimum value for this variable) and I am setting the dynamic system variables, so they are supposed to change, however the values of the variables do not change. Even after restarting the server, the values stay the  same. What might cause this problem?

Comment: You want to put this into my.cnf, the configuration file for MySQL.

Comment: I want to change the values dynamically form the shell script, so it should not be a fixed value. It used to work with my old server, i have no idea why it is not working now

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (set, server, variables) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 4):

This is a big long for a comment.

I don't know why this would have worked previously.  The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html) is pretty clear:

> If you change a global system variable, the value is remembered and
>   used for new connections until the server restarts. (To make a global
>   system variable setting permanent, you should set it in an option
>   file.)

Perhaps on your previous server, the new value happened to match the value in the configuration file.

Comment: right, true, I used to restart the server after each setting. However I am not very sure which configuration file my server is using, I looked for my.cnf file, and found that there are quite a lot of them in different places, so I am not sure as which one to change.

Comment: and also, does it mean that all of the dynamic system variables should be set in an option file? There are loads of those variables.

Comment: Start with the documentation . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html.

Answer (score 3):

For dynamically setting the variables in your program, you just need:

```
SET query_alloc_block_size = 1024
```

(Remove the GLOBAL)
Then it will work for current connection.